# Working with ui-views during ui router state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI router in an angular application where basic animations of views using ng-enter(-active) and ng-leave(-active) classes are not enough. I have already used $stateChangeStart event in an app before to scroll up before the statechange but I would like to work with the ui-views even more.

Therefore I tried to find out how the statechange process affects ui-view elements in DOM, but somehow I can't find what I am looking for.

The process I researched fires events in following order: stateChangeStart > viewContentLoading > stateChangeSuccess > viewContentLoaded. Unfortunately when I look at the DOM (using Chome dev console), only during the last breakpoint (viewContentLoaded) there are both ui-views in DOM (the "fromState ui-view" and the "toState ui-view").

I've been thinking of fading the former ui-view element, doing some other stuff and then fading the new ui-view element in so I was looking for an event where only the former ui-view exists, then both and then only the new. This way it seems to me that I should perform all the animations inside the viewContentLoaded callback which seems inappropriate.

Am I missing something in the whole concept or is there another events or approaches to this? Thanks in advance for any hints or links...